# Adding dependency injection to Nlog using Ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, nlog, ninject-extensions

I'm trying to add dependency injection to [Nlog](http://nlog-project.org/) using [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) for unit testing purposes, but I cannot get it to work. :(
I'm getting a NullReferenceException when calling GetCurrentClassLogger().
I'm new to both Nlog and Ninject, this is actually my first time using them.

**Main**

```
using NLog;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Extensions.Logging;
using Ninject.Extensions.Logging.NLog2;
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel(new NLogModule());
        var logFactory = kernel.Get<ILoggerFactory>();
        var run = new MyClass(logFactory);
    }
}
```

**MyClass**

```
using Ninject.Extensions.Logging;
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ILogger _log;

    public MyClass(ILoggerFactory logFactory)
    {
        _log = logFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        _log.Info("Doing work!");
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving it. Thanks to Claus Jørgensen helping me out on IRC :)

Apparently there is some auto binding in place when using the NLog extension so doing `new StandardKernel(new NLogModule());` would result in the module to be loaded twice.

**Main**

```
using Ninject;
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        var run = kernel.Get<MyClass>();
        run.DoWork();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.